# How to get items from arraylist on Button click?

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve items list saved in database and what to display items one by one from this list but did not understand how to get position. Please help.

code:

```
models = notificationDataBase.getAllNotificationsData();
CNotficationModel model = models.get()
```

Comment: please explain more what you want to do

Comment: Do you want to show it in a listView?